# I want to create a linked list in C and perform certain functions on it. But can't find the errors in my code

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

The function display does not print the id of a student, but some number. The value of pointers are assigned correctly and when I print them, they are as they should be. But I cannot print the id of the Student. Could you please help me with the problem?

I am getting this as output.

```
Enter Student ID
23
New Student Created
The id of student at position 1 is 12672416
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void displayList();
void insertAtFirst();
struct Student * createStudentNode();

struct Student {
    int id;
    struct Student * nextStudent;
};
struct Student * startStudent;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    insertAtFirst();
    displayList();
    return 0;
}

void displayList() {
    int x = 1;
    struct Student * tempStudent = (struct Student * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Student * ));
    if (startStudent == NULL) {
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
    } else {
        tempStudent = startStudent;

        while (tempStudent != NULL) {
            printf("The id of student at position %d is %d\n", x, tempStudent -> id);
            tempStudent = tempStudent -> nextStudent;
            x++;
        }
    }
}

void insertAtFirst() {
    struct Student * t;
    struct Student * tempStudent;

    tempStudent = createStudentNode();
    printf("Enter Student ID\n");
    scanf("%d", tempStudent -> id);
    printf("New Student Created\n");
    tempStudent -> nextStudent = NULL;

    if (startStudent == NULL) {
        startStudent = tempStudent;
    } else {
        tempStudent -> nextStudent = startStudent;
        startStudent = tempStudent;
    }
}

//This method creates a new Student structure and returns it address
struct Student * createStudentNode() {
    struct Student * n;
    n = (struct Student * ) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    n -> nextStudent = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",tempStudent->id)` -> `scanf("%d",&tempStudent->id)`

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, what happens if malloc fails? Your code will blow up. You should always validate the return value from dynamic allocations. Also, you've used 3 different variants to declare pointers. You should use one format, ideally `object *ptr;` (not `object* ptr;` and not `object * ptr;`).

Comment: OT: In `displayList` you should not be allocating memory for `tempStudent`. That doesn't make sense as you then immediately overwrite it with `tempStudent = startStudent;` There is no need for the `malloc` at all. What you have results in memory leaks.

Comment: @jarmod Thankyou! I'll take care of it.

Comment: $ cc temp_124.c
temp_124.c:44:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d", tempStudent -> id);
           ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.